# how to delay 'say' actions in siri proxy plugin

Tags: ruby, plugins, siri

I've started to play with Ruby on Rails to make some plugins for Siri Proxy Server.
I am inexperienced with Ruby but have manage the basics.

what I have done:

```
################ Commands

 listen_for (/show a demo to (.*)/i) do |name|
   show_demo
   request_completed
 end

################ Actions

 def show_demo(name)
    say "Hi #{name}, let me do a quick demo for You."  
        say "For example if You tell me 'Turn on sidelight' I will turn the sidelights in Living room like now..."  
          system "/usr/local/bin/tdtool --on 2"  
        say "That was the sidelights, and now if like I can turn on the gallery for You, just tell me 'turn on gallery' like so...  "  
        system "/usr/local/bin/tdtool --on 3"
        say "This only part of things I can do after mod."  
        say "Now I will turn all devices off..."  
          system "/usr/local/bin/tdtool --off 3"  
          system "/usr/local/bin/tdtool --off 2"  
        say " Thank You #{name}, and goodbye."

 end
```

The problem is when I'll start the demo all the actions`system "..."` are executed before Siri start to say anything .
How can I delay above action to put them in right place in time to execute them right after words I want?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `say` won't wait for Siri to actually say the words, it just sends a packet over to your iDevice and then goes on. The simplest approach i can think of would be to wait a few seconds, depending on how long the text is. So first we need a method that gives us the duration to wait (in seconds). I tried with the OSX built-in `say` command and got the following results:

```
$ time say "For example if You tell me 'Turn on sidelight' I will turn the sidelights in Living room like now..."
say   0,17s user 0,05s system 3% cpu 6,290 total

$ time say "That was the sidelights, and now if like I can turn on the gallery for You, just tell me 'turn on gallery' like so...  "
say   0,17s user 0,06s system 2% cpu 8,055 total

$ time say "This only part of things I can do after mod."
say   0,13s user 0,04s system 5% cpu 2,996 total
```

So this means we have the following data:

```
# Characters w/o whitespace   |   Seconds to execute
------------------------------+---------------------
                         77   |                6.290
                         87   |                8.055
                         34   |                2.996
```

This leaves us with an average of about `0.0875` seconds per character. You may need to evaluate the average time for your scenario yourself and with more samples. This function will wrap `say` and then wait until the text was spoken out by Siri:

```
def say_and_wait text, seconds_per_char=0.0875
  say text
  num_speakable_chars = text.gsub(/[^\w]/,'').size
  sleep num_speakable_chars * seconds_per_char
end
```

where `gsub(/[^\w]/,'')` will remove any non-word characters from the string. Now you can use this to simply say something and wait for it to be spoken out:

```
say_and_wait "This is a test, just checking if 0.875 seconds per character are a good fit."
```

Or you can also override the duration in special cases:

```
say_and_wait "I will wait for ten seconds here...", 10
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi padde,   thank You for Your fast reply but my rookie skills might failed. I added `def say_and_wait..` and then `say_and_wait "long sentence here..."` and when its long plugin crash , when its shot is working but no delay result. I would be grateful if You could do little but whole example how to write the code. Thank You